# PHP works outside function but wont work inside function

Tags: php

I'm trying to put the following code into a function as I need to use it quite a few times but with one variable changed ($subject) but it doesn't seem to be working. If I remove it from the function and run it, it works fine but as soon as it goes into the function and gets called it breaks so I'm not sure there is anything wrong with the code itself. I'm new to using PHP functions, but do I need to pass in everything or can it access variables outside of the function such as the $connect and $id variables which are defined above?

```
function count($subject){

    $getCount = $connect->prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM entries WHERE uid = :id AND subject = :subject');
    $getCount->execute(array(
        ':id' => $id, 
        ':subject' => $subject
    ));
    $rowCount = $getCount->fetchColumn();

    return $rowCount;
}

echo count("English");
```

Comment: possibly scope issue. try adding `global $connect;` after this line `function count($subject){`

Comment: Try to rename the function

Comment: Cheers guys, turns out it was a scope issue. I thought all PHP variables above function were global but it appears not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$connect` is no longer accessible inside the function. A simple, but bad fix would be this:

```
function count($subject){
    global $connect
```

A better fix would be for you to send in the `$connect` variable to the function:

```
function count($subject, $connect){
```

And change your function calls to

```
count("The subject", $connect)
```

Comment: Sorry for what has appeared to be the easiest question known to man! As all my variables are directly defined above the function I assumed they were all defined as global in PHP. It works perfectly now after passing in the necessary variables. Thanks.

Comment: @burg93, it sounds like you might want to spend some time reading the PHP documentation on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).